# conditional to evaluate structure (url) field and current_url

Tags: templates, conditionals, structure, url

I'm trying to create a conditional to determine if the structure entry url is the same as the global `{current_url}`. I created a structure field called, `{product_category}`. For some reason I cannot get conditional below to evaluate to true. Any idea what the issue is?

When callinng in template `{product_category}` I get the following output:

> http://localsite.com/index.php/online-store/business-compliance-materials/

When calling in template `{current_url}` I get the following output:

> http://localsite.com/index.php/online-store/business-compliance-materials

Here's my conditional:

`{if product_category == current_url . '/'} 
     True 
{if:else} 
     False 
{/if}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correct (the links aren't working) you're trying to check if {product_category} is equal to {current_url} if so you need the following.

```
{if '{product_category}' == '{current_url}'} 
    True 
{if:else} 
     False 
{/if}
```

Comment: That worked, however I ended up using Playa instead to categorize products. Thanks for the help, Chris!